# configuring log4j2.xml from log4j.xml

Tags: log4j, upgrade, log4j2

currently i am upgrading log4j version from 1.2.17 to 2.8.2 , to do that i need to configure log4j2.xml,  how to convert the below mentioned log4j.xml file to log4j2.xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout" />
  </appender>
  <appender name="RootFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="logs/webuif.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p %c: %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <appender name="ApplicationFileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="logs/ab.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p %c: %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <category name="com.abc" additivity="false">
    <priority value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="ApplicationFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  </category>
  <root>
    <priority value="warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="RootFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: [Check out the documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html)